# How to create opacity, to be compatible with IE 7+, Opera, Chrome, Safari 5, Mozilla 4+ and doesn't affect subelements

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can I create opacity, so it won't affect subelements, and it would be compatible with IE7+, Opera, Chrome, Safari 5, Mozilla 4+?
Currently I'm using

```
background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
```

But it's not compatible with Ie 7 and Ie 8.

Comment: You unfortunately can't reduce opacity on an element without affecting the child elements. It's just one of those things CSS can't do without some kind of hack.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
opacity: .8;
```

Opacity is a CSS command, values are from 0 (transparent) to 1 (solid)

Works on ie 8 at the least (only copy I can access)

If you want sub elements to be non transparent you can always

```
opacity : 1 !important;
```

Comment: Just an FYI: this won't work with IE7. Also, setting the opacity of subelements to 1 won't make them nontransparent.

Comment: Yeah, just clarifying. By the way, if you go to Developer Tools (F12) from IE8, you can switch into IE7 emulation mode. Click the button in the menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

From [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html):

```
opacity: .5; /* everything + ie9 */
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; /* ie8 */
filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* ie5-7 */
```

Make sure you keep them in that order for maximum compatibility. Be warned that IE's opacity wreaks havoc with text anti-aliasing and animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
opacity:.80; 
filter: alpha(opacity=80) // For IE
```

This will give the opacity of 80%.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try using [rgba.php](http://lea.verou.me/rgba.php/) along with regular RGBA colours.

For example (once rgba.php is installed), you can use:

> background: url('rgba.php/rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)');
>
> background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);